# jQuery show hide function not working correctly

Tags: jquery

Ok so I have this code

```
//<!--

  $(document).ready (function() {
 $('.topicsShow').hide();
 var i = 1;
 $('.clickFunc').each(function(){
     $(this).click(function(){ 
         $('.topicsShow:eq('+$(this).data('idf')+')').toggle('slow');
     });
     $(this).data('idf',i);
     i++;
});
  });

// -->
```

It didn't work correctly at first because of the var i = 0; so I changed to 1. Worked a wee bit better. Why is this? Can someone explain? 
Reason why it is not working perfectly correct is because when I click on my .clickFunc it opens one td element.I have a whole tr hidden, and your suppose to click the tr element above that (which is the category header) and it should open all the topics in that category. This code makes it so when I click it only opens one td element in the tr.

Can someone help me a little here?

```
<tr class="clickFunc">
  <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="topicsShow">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="topicsShow">
<td></td>
 <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="clickFunc">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="topicsShow">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

That is basic mock up of what is generated. There will be more topicsShow and more clickFunc if I add more categories/topics

Answer (score 0):

It's sometime not work because If u hard-coded the visibility style of those divs to "hidden" and jquery's "show" method can't revert that. Strangely, as opposed to "show" method, "hide" can revert hard-coded "visible" style with no problem. So, to hide/show elements as intended, you either have to use hide/show method combo without no visibility style hard-coding or use css method of jquery and set the visibility style as desire.

Comment: It is hardcoded style="display:none;" so if i take that off, and leave the .hide it should work? Like I said it's working to an extent...

Comment: My experience is that `jQuery.show()` can override a hard-coded `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('.topicsShow').hide();
    $('.clickFunc').each(function (i, elem) {
        //i and elem are parameters passed to .each;
        //i naturally increments.
        var self = elem; //cache object so that jQuery doesn't do several lookups
        self.data('idf', i).click(function (e) {
            $('.topicsShow:eq(' + self.data('idf') + ')').toggle('slow');
            e.preventDefault(); //cancel bubbling
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

My guess is that you need to assign `$(this).data('idf',i);` before the `click` handler.

If this doesn't help, please add some sample markup to your post.

**UPDATE:**

This works with your markup:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.topicsShow').hide(); //hide topics
    $('.clickFunc').each(function (i, elem) {
        var self = $(elem) //cache object
        self.click(function (e) {
            //.nextUntil('.clickFunc') === get all siblings until .clickFunc
            //.filter('.topicsShow') === select only elements that have the .topicsShow class
            self.nextUntil('.clickFunc').filter('.topicsShow').toggle('slow');
            e.preventDefault(); //cancel bubbling
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

The reason my original code didn't do anything is that I forgot to put `elem` into a jQuery wrapper (i.e., `$(elem)`).

`e.preventDefault();` does not prevent the click event. Instead, it prevents the click event from bubbling up to higher order elements (further up the ancestor tree). I included it as I assume you don't want anything else to happen after the `tr` elements are toggled. I also included `return false;` for the same reason (it may be redundant but I'm not sure if it is, so I included it anyway).

The purpose of [the `.data` function](http://api.jquery.com/data/) (which you were using in your question :) ) is to store arbitrary values (like variable values, or in this case, the value of `i`) to the matched DOM elements in the selector.

The code in your question does the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.topicsShow').hide(); //hide topics
    var i = 1;  //declare a var for incrementing
    $('.clickFunc').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            //:eq(0) or :eq(1) as this only loops twice, see notes in markup below
            //when you intialized `i` to 1, this became :eq(1) or :eq(2)
            $('.topicsShow:eq(' + $(this).data('idf') + ')').toggle('slow');
        });
        $(this).data('idf', i); //store the value of `i` (0 || 1) || (1 || 2) in the matched element
        i++; //increment `i`
    });
});
```

with this markup:

```
<tr class="clickFunc"><!-- with var i = 0; click handler toggles .topicsShow:eq(0)-->
    <td>clickFunc</td><!-- with var i = 1; click handler toggles .topicsShow:eq(1)-->
    <td>clickFunc</td>
</tr>
<tr class="topicsShow"><!-- .topicsShow:eq(0) -->
    <td>topicsShow</td>
    <td>topicsShow</td>
    <td>topicsShow</td>
    <td>topicsShow</td>
</tr>
<tr class="topicsShow"><!-- .topicsShow:eq(1) -->
    <td>topicsShow</td>
    <td>topicsShow</td>
    <td>topicsShow</td>
    <td>topicsShow</td>
</tr>
<tr class="clickFunc"><!-- click handler toggles :eq(2)-->
    <td>clickFunc</td><!-- with var i = 0; click handler toggles .topicsShow:eq(1)-->
    <td>clickFunc</td><!-- with var i = 1; click handler toggles .topicsShow:eq(2)-->
    <td>clickFunc</td>
    <td>clickFunc</td>
</tr>
<tr class="topicsShow"><!-- .topicsShow:eq(2) -->
    <td>topicsShow</td>
    <td>topicsShow</td>
    <td>topicsShow</td>
    <td>topicsShow</td>
</tr>
```

Hope this explains everything. :)

Comment: Will let you know. Its code is parsed with php handlers. Though I'll have to post some generated for ya.

Comment: pete, for some reason your code did not work at all. and can I ask why e.preventDefault(); is there? wouldn't that cancel the clicking?? Also can you answer me this question, ive never seen .data('idf',i) what is that?

Comment: I just tried this...

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() { 
$('.clickFunc').click(function() {  
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings('.topicsShow').toggle(); 
});  
  });
</script>

It opens them all at once